Does there exist analytic expression for the root of Bessel functions?
The root of the transcendental equation $x =\cos x$ has analytic expression: $$
D=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \arctan \left( 
\tan \left( 
\frac{t-\sin t +\frac{\pi}{2}}{2}
\right)
\right) dt + \frac{1 }{\pi}
$$
But I searched the google scholar and I have not found the analytic expression for the root of some other widely used function like Bessel function. In the mathematical physics classes, we only express our result to say some parameter are the first root of Bessel function $J_\mu(x)$.
Can we determine the analytic expression then?

Yes. Arctan (tan x) is not rigorously  x. https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/36297534. I can only find MANDARIN website with this formula

There is a complex integral solution in this Wolfram Community post, but it just plugs in $f(x)=J_0(x)$ into a formula for a function roots
